# Balance does not reflect internal transactions

Tags: internal-transactions

I am trying to cash out about $3k in Nft sales from the last 2 weeks. I see the Nft sale transactions under transactions (out) and internal transactions tab shows the ether proceeds. Both those definitely do not reflect in my wallet balance-why and how do I get my money? Wallet address is:
0xFE44c561543e2678Ac7eDf3A800efa0B011De327

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The two most recent internal transaction to your address are about 0,5Eth each. If you look at the the main 'Transaction' tab, you can see those assets were transferred away from your wallet some time after they were received.

All of the Ethers that address received has corresponding transfers out, to various addresses. So the balance is correct.